# what is the difference between a Movie and a TV Show in iTunes Library?

Tags: iphone, itunes, video

what is the difference between a Movie and a TV Show in iTunes Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between those two categories is how iTunes groups things by default. In the Movies view, there's not grouping. All movies are displayed alphabetically by default. In the TV Show view things are grouped by show -- so you get a single icon for each show and you drill down to access the episodes within the show.